# What is wrong with this template partial specialization code?

Tags: c++, templates

I am using the following code :

```
template<typename t>
struct foo
{
    foo(t var)
    {
        std::cout << "Regular Template";
    }
};



template<typename t>
struct foo<t*>
{
    foo(t var)
    {
        std::cout << "partially specialized Template " << t;
    }
};


int main()
{
    int* a = new int(12);

    foo<int*> f(a); //Since its a ptr type it should call specialized template

}
```

However I am getting the error

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'foo<t>::foo(int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int *' to 'int'
```

Comment: You've told the compiler `t` is `int`, yet you pass an `int *` where it expects a `t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor of the both templates takes a `t` by value, which in your example is `int`, not `int*`. To make this compile use

```
template<typename t>
struct foo<t*>
{
    foo(t* var)
    {
        std::cout << "partially specialized Template " << var;
    }
};
```

if that fits your logic, else pass an `int` to the constructor. [(Live)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe4240780a847d56)